# Why the space usage of Ubuntu Windows Subsystem of Linux is lower than the Microsoft Store Download package?

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my PC the disk usage of `C:\Users\DD\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs` is only `93MB`, but the download package is more than `240MB` when I install it.

Is there other dirs also used for `wsl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some filesystem objects under hidden folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` (their names can depend on WSL version):

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
```

This folder occupies approximately **`214.4` [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)** (returned from the following PowerShell code snippet):

```
((Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Canonical*" -Recurse -Force) | 
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum/1MB
```

**More detailed** - *copy&paste* the following code snippet to an open **elevated** PowerShell prompt:

```
# run elevated
$WinApps = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps'                       # parent
(Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\*Ubuntu*" -Force -Dir).Name            # Ubuntu On Windows
(Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\*Ubuntu*" -Force -Dir -Recurse).Name   # subfolders
(Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\Can*" -Force -Recurse ) | 
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -Maximum               # measure files
(Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\Can*\install*" -Force -Recurse )       # the greatest file
```

**Result**:

> ```
> Windows PowerShell
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading personal and system profiles took 649ms.
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> # run elevated
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $WinApps = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps'                       # parent
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\*Ubuntu*" -Force -Dir).Name            # Ubuntu On Windows
> CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\*Ubuntu*" -Force -Dir -Recurse).Name   # subfolders
> AppxMetadata
> Assets
> microsoft.system.package.metadata
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\Can*" -Force -Recurse ) |
> >>     Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -Maximum               # measure files
>
> Count    : 52
> Average  :
> Sum      : 224813301
> Maximum  : 223983209
> Minimum  :
> Property : Length
>
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-ChildItem "$WinApps\Can*\install*" -Force -Recurse )       # the greatest file
>
>
>     Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.81
>     7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
>
>
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
> ----                -------------         ------ ----
> -a----       23.08.2018     20:50      223983209 install.tar.gz
> ```