# How do I reduce the size of WSL rootfs?

Tags: mount, disk-usage, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL 1. My WSL Ubuntu 18.04 rootfs (`C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows.../LocalState/rootfs/`) size on my `C:` drive is very large due to duplicated data from a mounted disk drive (`M:`). I would like to remove the duplicated data without affecting the data that is on my `M:` drive and without adversely affecting my WSL setup. Ideally, I would also like to avoid duplicating the data to my `C:` drive in the future so I don't put the extra stress on the SSD.

[image]

I have tried to unmount the drive from within WSL using `sudo umount /mnt/m`, but it did not reduce the size of the rootfs on my `C:` drive. I am afraid of just deleting the data because it is highly recommended not to modify anything within that rootfs from Windows, and I don't want to mess up the WSL image or the data on my `M:` drive.

Comment: Version 1 or Version 2 ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2 Please advise.

Comment: WSL Version 1. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
You can safely reduce the size of a WSL instance's rootfs by deleting `/mnt/<DRIVE_LETTER>/*` from the WSL rootfs after unmounting the underlying disk from within WSL instance. In my case, my WSL instance had a lot of cached data from Windows' `M:` drive stored in `/mnt/m`. I cleaned it safely from within the WSL instance by:

```
sudo umount /mnt/m
rm -rf /mnt/m/*
```

If you are paranoid, first use `mount` from within your WSL instance to verify the drive you want to clean. Then after running the unmount command (`sudo unmount /mnt/<DRIVE_LETTER>`), run `mount` again and verify the drive no longer appears in the list. Then you can safely proceed to use `rm -rf` on the files from within the WSL instance to wipe the cached data without affecting the data on the underlying Windows disk.

---- My Findings ----

Looks like WSL 1 uses that rootfs folder as a data cache. I noticed after unmounting my `M:` drive from within WSL with `sudo umount /mnt/m` that some of the folders' permissions changed while others didn't (notice the color difference in the below image which was taken after unmounting `/mnt/m`). The folders whose permissions didn't change are the folders that were taking up space on my Windows' `C:` drive in that `rootfs` folder.

[image: listing of /mnt/m after unmounting]

My Dropbox folder contributed to 11 GB on my `C:` drive but takes up much more on my `M:` drive. Since I knew it was already backed-up on Dropbox's servers, I wiped it from within WSL 1 (after having unmounted `/mnt/m` from within WSL) with the following: `rm -rf /mnt/m/Dropbox` then checked and confirmed from Windows with WinDirStat that my `C:` drive gained 11 GB more free space while my `M:` drive's Dropbox folder was unaffected. I closed the WSL window and reopened it to trigger auto-mount of my drives. Then checked `/mnt/m/Dropbox` and it was there with everything again. I unmounted `/mnt/m` and proceeded to delete everything from within WSL with: `rm -rf /mnt/m/*`. I double checked my M drive again - all files still there. Then I double checked how WSL behaved by exiting and re-launching it. `ls -la /mnt/m` showed everything still there. Now my rootfs on C drive is very small... Nice!

[image: listing of windirstat showing zero space used by /mnt/m]